# C# Console text alignment issue with string.Padding()

Tags: c#, .net, string, console-application

```
string s = "cat".PadRight(8);
string s2 = "poodle".PadRight(8);

Console.Write(s);
Console.WriteLine("feline");
Console.Write(s2);
Console.WriteLine("canine");

Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i += 8)
{
   Console.Write(string.Format("{0} record(s) found.".PadRight(30, '.'), i));
   Console.WriteLine("(DONE).");
}
Console.Read();
```

This gives me this output
[image]

Why those `(DONE)` aren't aligned properly like `feline and canine` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

`string.Format("{0} record(s) found.", i).PadRight(30, '.')`

Actually `.PadRight(30, '.')` was *inside* the `string.Format` call, so the string was first padded and then formated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i += 8)
            {
                if (i<10) Console.Write("0"+string.Format("{0} record(s) found.".PadRight(30, '.'), i));  
                else Console.Write(string.Format("{0} record(s) found.".PadRight(30, '.'), i));
                Console.WriteLine("(DONE).");
            }
```